# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2) - every time I use apt-get install

Tags: dpkg

I am running 64-bit Ubuntu 13.04. I tried to install `cairo-dock` as follows:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa` -- went well, no errors.
2. `sudo apt-get update` -- went well, no errors.
3. `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins` -- error

This is the console output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cairo-dock-core cairo-dock-data cairo-dock-plug-ins-data
  cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-python cairo-dock-plug-ins-integration
  compiz-plugins curl libetpan15 libgldi3
Suggested packages:
  cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-mono
  cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-ruby
  cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-vala gnote
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cairo-dock cairo-dock-core cairo-dock-data cairo-dock-plug-ins
  cairo-dock-plug-ins-data cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-python
  cairo-dock-plug-ins-integration compiz-plugins curl libetpan15 libgldi3
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 26.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-data all 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [468 kB]
Get:2 **link** raring/universe libgldi3 amd64 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [352 kB]
Get:3 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-core amd64 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [1,125 kB]
Get:4 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-plug-ins-data all 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [4,190 kB]
Get:5 **link** raring-updates/main curl amd64 7.29.0-1ubuntu3.1 [149 kB]
Get:6 **link** raring/universe libetpan15 amd64 1.0-5 [286 kB]
Get:7 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-plug-ins amd64 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [871 kB]
Get:8 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-plug-ins-integration amd64 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [59.9 kB]
Get:9 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-python all 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [16.0 kB]
Get:10 **link** raring/universe cairo-dock all 3.2.1-0ubuntu1 [8,738 B]
Get:11 **link** raring-updates/universe compiz-plugins amd64 1:0.9.9~daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1 [2,764 kB]
Fetched 10.3 MB in 2min 1s (84.8 kB/s)                                         
Selecting previously unselected package cairo-dock-data.
**dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'linux-headers-3.8.0-19': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)**
```

The install gets stuck on the `dpkg` line. This error occurs every time I try to install a program using `apt-get install`.

Comment: Can you please show us exactly the steps you follow to install a package? Feel free to include as much info as you can, even something that won't feel relevant, so we can help you.

Comment: @rahmu I already added the full details of the process in the terminal..

Comment: "Input/output error" <-- your disk or filesystem is having problems. Please consult your system log (`/var/log/syslog`) for some more clues on this. It is likely that your disk is failing or that it is encountering severe filesystem errors.

Comment: how to find clues in syslog? what to look for?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I guess three states:

1. Your `linux-headers-3.8.0-19  deb file` was damaged. (In this case, you should re-install it.)
2. You should play with `apt systems` after upgrade with `dpkg -a --configure` then `apt-get -f dist-upgrade` or your task, maybe : `apt-get -f install`
3. Your deb package has a bug in postinst, if it state will be true, you can handle in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-686-pae.postinst` ,

Comment: how to reinstall linux-headers-3.8.0-19 deb file? cause I cant install anything using apt-get.. the E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2) always shows up if I try to install anything..

Comment: on your 3rd state.. it seems I don't have that dir bash: /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-686-pae.postinst: No such file or directory

Comment: `rm /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.8.0-19*; apt-get --reinstall install linux-headers-3.8.0-19`

Comment: i look up the dir but it says it does not exists.. do i have a different path for it?

Comment: directory is true, it's default dir on `debian-base`  for temp deb files, may be you don't have named file.

Comment: I cd into /var/cache/apt/archives and these are the result lock  partial

Comment: So just `reinstall`